# multi-core processing for for loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

`enter code here`I want to make used for the multi-core processing in order to speed up my function to use it with larger inputs, i am showing here simple example inputs:

which takes as an input

```
C0x = [[2.969129, 3.065011, 3.294439],
       [3.087682, 1.674345, 2.930011],
       [3.355765, 2.863887, 2.588477]]

C0y = [[6.748940, 9.673919, 7.662236],
       [9.527495, 11.328892, 10.147356],
       [7.738452, 10.280770, 7.684719]]

C0xy = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

C0yx = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

Cxx1 = [[2.970383, 3.065395, 3.295505],
        [3.088111, 1.674282, 2.930299],
        [3.356823, 2.864131, 2.589346]]

Cyy1 = [[6.733786, 9.656677, 7.646381],
        [9.510379, 11.309615, 10.129516],
        [7.722598, 10.262803, 7.668157]]

Cxy1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

Cyx1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

dCx = [array([[-0.88391347, -0.9165879 , -1.00445679],
        [-0.9102315 , -0.94390882, -1.03437531],
        [-0.99567547, -1.03249243, -1.13146452]]),
 array([[-0.93911752, -0.49819029, -0.88115751],
        [-0.51945798, -0.2755809 , -0.48739065],
        [-0.87413297, -0.46370905, -0.82018765]])]
dCy = [array([[4.54319981, 6.52256593, 5.20680836],
        [6.38565572, 9.16779592, 7.31840445],
        [5.19995576, 7.46547485, 5.95950073]]),
 array([[ 9.36071422, 11.09190807,  9.94111537],
        [10.98180048, 13.0128158 , 11.66270877],
        [ 9.93855597, 11.7766108 , 10.55478873]])]
dCxy = [array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]
dCyx = [array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]
```

This function calculates the values of the matrices A and B by first initializing several matrices with zeros, then looping through the free parameters and measurements to calculate the elements of A and B.

The matrices Dx, Dy, Dxy, and Dyx are calculated by subtracting the initial covariance matrices (C0x, C0y, C0xy, and C0yx) from the measured covariance matrices (Cxx_err, Cyy_err, Cxy_err, and Cyx_err).

The loop then calculates the values for the matrices Ax, Ay, Axy, and Ayx by summing the dot product of the partial derivative matrices with their respective transposes. These matrices are then concatenated to form the matrix A.

Finally, the loop calculates the values for the matrices Bx, By, Bxy, and Byx by summing the dot product of the partial derivative matrices with the corresponding error matrices. These matrices are then concatenated to form the matrix B

```
def defineMatrices(C0x, C0y, C0xy, C0yx, Cxx_err, Cyy_err, Cxy_err, Cyx_err, dCx, dCy, dCxy,dCyx):
    Nk = len(dCx)  # number of free parameters
    Nm = len(C0x)  # number of measurements
   

    Ax = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Ay = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Axy = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Ayx = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])

    A = np.zeros([4 * Nk, Nk])

    Bx = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    By = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    Bxy = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    Byx = np.zeros([Nk, 1])

    B = np.zeros([4 * Nk, 1])

    ##

    Dx = (Cxx_err[0:Nm, :] - C0x[0:Nm, :])  ### dk ?
    Dy = (Cyy_err[0:Nm, :] - C0y[0:Nm, :])
    Dxy = (Cxy_err[0:Nm, :] - C0xy[0:Nm, :])
    Dyx = (Cyx_err[0:Nm, :] - C0yx[0:Nm, :])

    ##

    for i in range(Nk):  ## i represents each quad
        # print('done A:', 100.* i ,'%')
        for j in range(Nk):
            Ax[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dCx[i], dCx[j].T))
            Ay[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dCy[i], dCy[j].T))
            Axy[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dCxy[i], dCxy[j].T))
            Ayx[i, j] = np.sum(np.dot(dCyx[i], dCyx[j].T))
        A[i, :] = Ax[i, :]
        A[i + Nk, :] = Ay[i, :]
        A[i + 2 * Nk, :] = Axy[i, :]
        A[i + 3 * Nk, :] = Ayx[i, :]

    ##

    for i in range(Nk):
        Bx[i] = np.sum(np.dot(dCx[i], Dx.T))
        By[i] = np.sum(np.dot(dCy[i], Dy.T))
        Bxy[i] = np.sum(np.dot(dCxy[i], Dxy.T))
        Byx[i] = np.sum(np.dot(dCyx[i], Dyx.T))
        B[i] = Bx[i]
        B[i + Nk] = By[i]
        B[i + 2 * Nk] = Bxy[i]
        B[i + 3 * Nk] = Byx[i]

    return A, B
```

The output from this function is A and B

`A, B = defineMatrices(C0x, C0y, C0xy, C0yx, Cxx1, Cyy1, Cxy1, Cyx1, dCx, dCy, dCxy,dCyx)`

```
A = [[26.203265, 17.026796],
     [17.026796, 11.763451],
     [1138.015961, 1913.702747],
     [1913.702747, 3238.589801],
     [0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0]]

B = [-0.016327,     -0.011957,     -2.966823,     -5.028449,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0]
```

I tried to modify the function as following:

```
from itertools import repeat
import copy
from scipy.io import savemat, loadmat
from os.path import exists
import math
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Process
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def compute_Ax(i, dCx, Nk):
    return np.array([np.sum(np.dot(dCx[i], dCx[j].T)) for j in range(Nk)])

def compute_Ay(i, dCy, Nk):
    return np.array([np.sum(np.dot(dCy[i], dCy[j].T)) for j in range(Nk)])

def compute_Axy(i, dCxy, Nk):
    return np.array([np.sum(np.dot(dCxy[i], dCxy[j].T)) for j in range(Nk)])

def compute_Ayx(i, dCyx, Nk):
    return np.array([np.sum(np.dot(dCyx[i], dCyx[j].T)) for j in range(Nk)])

def defineMatrices_mp(C0x, C0y, C0xy, C0yx, Cxx_err, Cyy_err, Cxy_err, Cyx_err, dCx, dCy, dCxy, dCyx, use_mp=True):
    Nk = len(dCx)  # number of free parameters
    Nm = len(C0x)  # number of measurements
   
    Ax = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Ay = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Axy = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    Ayx = np.zeros([Nk, Nk])
    A = np.zeros([4 * Nk, Nk])
    Bx = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    By = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    Bxy = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    Byx = np.zeros([Nk, 1])
    B = np.zeros([4 * Nk, 1])

    ##

    Dx = (Cxx_err[0:Nm, :] - C0x[0:Nm, :])  ### dk ?
    Dy = (Cyy_err[0:Nm, :] - C0y[0:Nm, :])
    Dxy = (Cxy_err[0:Nm, :] - C0xy[0:Nm, :])
    Dyx = (Cyx_err[0:Nm, :] - C0yx[0:Nm, :])

    ##

    if use_mp:

        with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as p:

            # compute Ax, Ay, Axy, Ayx in parallel for all i
            results = p.starmap(compute_Ax, [(i, dCx, Nk) for i in range(Nk)])
            for i in range(Nk):
                Ax[i, :] = results[i]

            results = p.starmap(compute_Ay, [(i, dCy, Nk) for i in range(Nk)])
            for i in range(Nk):
                Ay[i, :] = results[i]

            results = p.starmap(compute_Axy, [(i, dCxy, Nk) for i in range(Nk)])
            for i in range(Nk):
                Axy[i, :] = results[i]

            results = p.starmap(compute_Ayx, [(i, dCyx, Nk) for i in range(Nk)])
            for i in range(Nk):
                Ayx[i, :] = results[i]

            A[0:Nk, :] = Ax
            A[Nk:2*Nk, :] = Ay
            A[2*Nk:3*Nk, :] = Axy
           
    A[:Nk, :] = Ax
    A[Nk:2*Nk, :] = Ay
    A[2*Nk:3*Nk, :] = Axy
    A[3*Nk:4*Nk, :] = Ayx
    return A
A = defineMatrices_mp(C0x, C0y, C0xy, C0yx, Cxx1, Cyy1, Cxy1, Cyx1, dCx, dCy, dCxy, dCyx, use_mp=True)

I expected the same A and B results above But it seems that it wenth through an infinit loop:
```

Comment: You can't run a local function in a process pool. The function must be globally (on module level) accessible.

Comment: @MichaelButscher actually i haven't any experience with doing multi processing before, do you have any suggestions that i can follow for my code

Comment: @Accelerator you need to move `compute_Ai` outside the `defineMatrices_mp` function so it is accessible at the module level. Child processes spawned by `mp.Pool` need to be able to `import` the target function. You should pass *all* required inputs to the target function instead of binding them using a wrapper. If you have large amounts of constant data, you can pass them to the pool's initialization function, and assign them to the global namespace of the worker process in order to reduce how much data is sent back and forth to the worker (overhead which may slow down computation)

Comment: @Aaron sorry i am completely new to do this kind of processing i have tried to check simple python example and apply the same in my code but did not manage to find the answered, i would appreciate detailed explanation with examples using my code